# Reading data from table (HTML, JAVAscript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this table that receive from the server:
(with ajax):

```
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#MyTable tbody').append("<tr>"d
             +"<td>" +data[i].A+ "</td><td>" 
             +data[i].B
             +"</td><td><input type='text' value='"
             +data[i].C+"'/></td><td><input type='text' value='"
             + data[i].D+"'/></td>"
             + "</tr>");
        });
```

C and D are edit text, that the user can change. after the changing by the user I want to "take" the all new data from the table and send it by ajax with JSON.
how can I read the data to a JSON?

I start to write one but I am stuck on:

```
function saveNewData(){

    var newData= ...
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "save",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
    newData: newData},
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
    ...
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
    }); 
}
```

thank you

Comment: add some classes to the 3rd and 4th column inputs... select them by class... would you like to read the data from the last row or from all the rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
function getUserData()
{
    var newData = new Array();
    $.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'),function(key,val){
        var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text]");          
        var fileldValues = {};
        fileldValues['c'] = $(inputF[0]).val();
        fileldValues['d'] = $(inputF[1]).val();

        //if you want to add A and B, then add followings as well
        fileldValues['a'] = $($(this).children()[0]).text();
        fileldValues['b'] = $($(this).children()[1]).text();
        newData.push(fileldValues);
    });
    return JSON.stringify(newData);
}

function saveNewData(){

var newData = getUserData();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "save",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
    newData: newData},
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(data) {
    ...
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
}); 
}
```

Comment: How can I add row A and row B to "newData"?

Comment: How do I add an addition to C & D rows, the A & B rows to "newData"?

Comment: Thank you.
and if I just want to return "real" array not one string?

Comment: There is lot of data in the table. I want Just to send JSON (not string).

Comment: If you want to get real json object you can simply remove "JSON.stringify" function.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/yGXYh/1/

small demo based on answer from Nishan:

```
var newData = new Array();
$.each($('#MyTable tbody tr'), function (key, val) {
    var inputF = $(this).find("input[type=text]");
    var fileldValues = {};
    fileldValues['c'] = $(inputF[0]).val();
    fileldValues['d'] = $(inputF[1]).val();
    newData.push(fileldValues);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Answer (score 1):

use the jquery `on` event binding
try somthing like this. [Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/yGXYh/3/)

```
$('#MyTable').on('keyup', 'tr', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var dataA = $this.find('td:nth-child(1)').text() // to get the value of A
    var dataB = $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text() // to get the value of B
    var dataC = $this.find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input').val() // to get the value of C
    var dataD = $this.find('td:nth-child(4)').find('input').val() // to get the Valur of D

    // $.ajax POST to the server form here 
    //  this way you only posting one row to the server at the time

});
```

I don't normaly do that I would use a data binding libarray such as `Knockoutjs` or `AngularJS`